# HP ProLiant DL380 G7 (P410i) compatible drives

Tags: storage, hp, hp-proliant, ssd, hp-smart-array

I have recently been looking to do an upgrade on my server recently by upgrading to using SSDs (2.5 inch). I have done a lot of late night googling and have found that many drives have an issue with the RAID card in the machine where the fans will ramp up and even [shutdown the system](http://dascomputerconsultants.com/HPCompaqServerDrives.htm). With more looking, the recommendations are to just buy the HP drives, as they will have all of the monitoring features and are known to work. I have found a drive (HP 690816-001 MO0400FCTRP) that I think will work, but when I look it up on the [compatibility list](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c01677101&docLocale=en_US), I cannot find the drive. Is this drive compatible with my server?

Comment: That server is very old. Are you sure you need SSDs on that platform, versus investing into something Gen8 or newer?

Comment: Yes, 6gbps and the speed of the server itself is enough for me. I don't have the money for anything newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since about a year has passed, I thought I should probably update this.

Get Kingston A400 SSDs. They work great and will not spin up the fans.

Comment: Confirm kingston A400 works great on ML350p gen8 with p420i raid controller.